# Multi bluetooth device Connection using EAAccessory framework

Tags: ios, ios6, ios7, eaaccessory

This question might seem silly but since im new to IOS Developement i ask it again.

- Can we connect to multiple devices at a time in IOS using the EAAccessory framework?
- What is the maximum data rate for an Iphone, Ipad mini, Ipad, Ipod using bluetooth connection?
- Will the data rate change according to the framework used in the application? If so, then what is the maximum data rate for the Iphone, Ipad mini, Ipad, Ipod?

Thanks in Advance

Ramnathpraveen G

Answer (score 0):

I only have an answer to your first question. 
Yes it is possible. I just did a small test with a iPhone 5c and 2 accessories connected via Bluetooth. I can see that these accessories can connect at the same time. 
I recommend that you give the EADemo a try to test more scenario's.

I do not have information regarding your your other 2 questions.

Comment: Hi. I removed the signature from your post; see http://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior for why